# Найти строку в List<T> выбранную в ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Имеется:

```
public class AlbumResponse
{
    public string aid { get; set; }
    public string owner_id { get; set; }
    public string artist { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string duration { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class Audio
{
    public List<AlbumResponse> response { get; set; }
}
```

Парсинг строки с ВК(аудио)

```
string str = string.Format(
                "https://api.vk.com/method/audio.get?uid={0}&count=3&access_token={1}",
                VKUser.UserId, VKUser.AccessToken);

var responseText = VkRequest(str);
Audio audio = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Audio>(responseText);
```

Вывод песен в ListBox

```
foreach (var item in audio.response)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(item.artist + " - " + item.title);
}
```

Выбор песни из списка в ListBox двойным кликом:

```
private void listBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selected = (string)listBox1.SelectedItem; 
}
```

Как мне теперь выбрать данную композицию из audio.response? и выбрать данную url этой композиции?

Comment: Тут можно было бы просто через Binding привязать List<AlbumRasponse> к listbox1. Тогда у вас SelectedItem будет не string а AlbumResponse. Очень удобно и красиво. Если нужно могу показать как привязать List<T> к listbox1

Comment: Ну или глупый вариант: var selectedItem = audio.First(w=>w.artist + " - " + w.title == selected);

Comment: Переменную `audio` Вы нигде не сохраняете, я правильно понимаю? поэтому доступа у Вас к ней нет в `listBox1_DoubleClick`, так?

Comment: Это WinForms или WPF?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Тут можно было бы просто через Binding привязать List к listbox1. Тогда у вас SelectedItem будет не string а AlbumResponse. Очень удобно и красиво. Если нужно могу показать как привязать List к listbox1

Вот простой пример биндинга:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            audio = new List<AlbumResponse>()
            {
                new AlbumResponse()
                {
                    title = "Goodbye to yesterday",
                    artist = "Elina Born and Stid Rasta"
                }
            };
            Songs.ItemsSource = audio;

        }
        public List<AlbumResponse> audio { get; set; }
    }
```

А вот, что делается в XAML

```
<Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="Songs">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" Foreground="Black"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding artist}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

Таким образом мы легко можем редактировать наш список не переводя его в список строк, что вас будет удобно и просто. И изменяя artists на форме все будет автоматически меняться.

Answer (score 0):

Это WinForm.
Спасибо за подсказку, связал

```
   listBox1.DataSource = album.response;
```

и потом:

```
   var selected = (AlbumResponse)listBox1.SelectedItem;
   axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = selected.url;
```

Все получилось :) музло заиграло при двойном клике на песню из списка, но было найдено и другое решение этой проблемы : до связывания сделал вот так и получился тот же результат:

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = urls[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
```